# INotifyPropertyChanged not updating UI in DataTemplate, XAML, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I want to display multiple rectangles with some properties, which I store in an Array of Arrays. The XAML for displaying looks like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Views.SomeView">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ObjectRowTemplate">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=color, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="15" Width="30"  StrokeThickness="1px" Stroke="Blue" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                    <catel:EventToCommand DisableAssociatedObjectOnCannotExecute="False">
                        <catel:EventToCommand.Command>
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}" Path="DataContext.ObjectClickedCommand"  />
                        </catel:EventToCommand.Command>

                        <catel:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
                            <Binding Path="."  />
                        </catel:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
                    </catel:EventToCommand>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Rectangle>   
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ObjectColumnTemplate">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ObjectRowTemplate}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Canvas Background="Black" Width="{Binding CanvasWidth}" Height="600">
        <Grid>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindedProperty, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ObjectColumnTemplate}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

there is a `StackPanel` with a canvas inside which shows the array of array via the two defined `DataTemplate`s, by creating a `Rectangle` for each "slot" in the `Array`.

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModel : AdvancedViewModelBase
    {
        public CreateGameFieldViewModel()
        {
            ObjectClickedCommand = new Command<Object>(ObjectClicked);

            Objects = new Objects[15][];
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                Objects[i] = new Object[15];
                for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                {
                    Objects[i][j] = new Object(someparams);
                }
            }
        }

        private Object _selectedObject;

        private Object[][] _object;

        public Object[][] Objects
        {
            get { return _object; }
            set
            {
                _object = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Objects));
            }
        }

        public int CanvasWidth { get; set; } = 450;

        public Command<OPbject> ObjectClickedCommand { get; set; }

        public void ObjectClicked(Object object)
        {
            if (object != null)
            {
                _selectedObject = object;
            }
        }

        public void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // Modify _currentObject
            _currentObject.color = Brushes.Blue;

            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Objects));
        }
    }
}
```

The property binding with the viewmodel works fine, the properties are set as defined. By clicking on a `Rectangle`, the object which is bound to, is now set as `_selectedObject` and can be modified by the arrow keys, which also works like a charm.

Since I modified one object of the array of arrays, which I am binding to the DataTemplate, I have to notify my UI which I am doing by then line `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Objects));` (used Nuget: Catel) after the modification.

Unfortunately the UI does not get updated. I checked everything, the object in the array of arrays contains the modifications.

I guess it doesn't work because of the `DataTemplate`s I used.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Unless you don't add or remove objects from `Objects`, it should be sufficient that the array element implements INotifyPropertyChanged and fires the PropertyChanged event for all relevant properties. As a note, setting `Mode=OneWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless.

Comment: Did you try managing this with an ObservableCollection of the changed objects?  Sometimes an object inside a collection never gets the event raised to the UI if it is bound to the collection itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue in UWP when the `ObservableCollection` of the second level of the parent `ObservableCollection` won't update UI in `DataTemplate` though it has implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

It seems like `Routing` does not work for the nested `ObservableCollection`.

I also was not able to force the method `myObject.OnPropertyChanged('PropertyName')`.

So the solution was folllowing:

1. Dynamically populate `Tag` property of the `DataTemplate` using `ObjectToString` converter. So the `Tag` has a string like **Author-3**. Where is **3** is the **ID** of the **Author** entity and as result we have unique identifiers for all objects created on base of `DataTemplate`.
2. Within code just find all objects via `Object Type` and the `Tag` name (i.e. Author-3) and do what you need to change its any property.
3. And you have working UI!

In my case I will provide chunks of code and you will have  whole imagination what's going on.

**XAML**

```
 xmlns:myconverters="using:MyProjectFolder.Converters" 


 <UserControl.Resources> 
        <myconverters:LoaderOnlineToColorConverter x:Key="MyLoaderOnlineToColorConverter"/>
       
        
        <muxc:StackLayout  x:Key="UniformGridLayout2" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="UnitLoaderItemTemplate" x:DataType="x1:UnitLoader">
            <Grid BorderBrush="Gray"  BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,5,0,0" Padding="5,0,5,5" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel IsDoubleTapEnabled="True" DoubleTapped="Unit_DoubleTapped" Tag="{x:Bind DeviceID}" 
                            Grid.Column="0" Padding="2,0,2,4" Margin="0,5,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal"   
                            BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{x:Bind FullName}">
                    <FontIcon Tag="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource MyDeviceIDToControlNameConverter}}" 
                              Foreground="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource MyLoaderOnlineToColorConverter}}"
                              FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE701;" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,2,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DeviceName}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" /> 
</StackPanel>
```

NOTE: this line `Foreground="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource MyLoaderOnlineToColorConverter}}"` exactly does not work so we have another one

```
Tag="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource MyDeviceIDToControlNameConverter}}"
```

**C# The converters**

```
 public class DeviceIDToControlNameConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            var controlName = "Unit-";

            if (value is UnitLoader)
            {
                controlName = "Loader-" + ((UnitLoader)value).DeviceID;
            }
            else if (value is UnitLoader)
            {
                controlName = "Track-" + ((UnitTrack)value).DeviceID;
            }            

            return controlName;
        }
}
     public class LoaderOnlineToColorConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
            {
                SolidColorBrush color;
    
                if (value is UnitLoader)
                {
                    var isOnline = ((UnitLoader)value).IsOnline;
    
                    if (isOnline)
                    {
                        color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.YellowGreen);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
                }
               
    
                return color;
            } 
    
        }
```

**C# The code to change the property of all objects**

```
string tagName = "Loader-" + unitLoader.DeviceID.ToString();
var fontIcon = FindControl<FontIcon>(this, typeof(FontIcon), tagName);
if (fontIcon != null)
{
  fontIcon.Foreground = unitLoader.IsOnline ? deviceOnline : deviceOffline;
}
```

**C# Method to search all objects via Type and Tag**

```
public static T FindControl<T>(UIElement parent, Type targetType, string ControlName) where T : FrameworkElement
        {

            if (parent == null) return null;

            if (parent.GetType() == targetType && ((T)parent).Tag != null && ((T)parent).Tag.ToString() == ControlName)
            {
                return (T)parent;
            }
            T result = null;
            int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                UIElement child = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

                if (FindControl<T>(child, targetType, ControlName) != null)
                {
                    result = FindControl<T>(child, targetType, ControlName);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```